# the Div(rollover button / picture ) is not resizing when windows shink

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

when i resize the window of my browser (firefox/chrome) the div is also moving and it's not resizing. I don't find any answers on stackoverflow yet. please help.

this is what actually happen : https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/p480x480/944750_668339529872645_486882136_n.jpg

code :

```
position: absolute;
width: 80%;
height: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

there must be some overlaping of css properties so you can replace it with following...

```
position: relative;
width: 80%!important;
height: 50%!important;
```

check now.

Comment: hello sir, this code didnt work :(

this is what actually happen : 

https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/p480x480/944750_668339529872645_486882136_n.jpg